# How to change the button text on fetch response in react native?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, jsx, styling

I want to change the button text based on the response returned from server.How do it possible?
my response look like this

```js
{
"responseHeader": {
"type": "314",
"status": "200",
"message": "Successfully found the profile"
},
"neighbourProfile": [{
"no_of_mutual_friends": "0",
"is_anchored": "1",
},
{
"no_of_mutual_friends": "0",
"is_anchored": "0"
}]
}
```

I want to change button text based on status `is_anchored` , if it is 0, i want button text as `friends` otherwise `add` , How can i do that?This is my react part

```js
return (
      <Card>
      <CardSection>
      <Image style ={styles.thumbnail_style} source={{uri : profile_image_url}} />
       <View style= {styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
    <Text style={styles.userStyle}>{username}</Text>
        <Image source={require('./src/Images/profession_cell.png')}/><Text style={styles.textStyle}>
      No profession to show</Text>
      <Text style={styles.friendStyle}>{no_of_mutual_friends} Mutual friends</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonStyle}><Button color="#00BFA5" title="Add" onPress={() =>console.log("clicked")}>
      </Button></View>
      </CardSection>

      </Card>
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your previous question, after you set neighbours in state:

```js
.then((responseData) =>this.setState({neighbours: responseData.neighbourProfile}));
```

You can render the buttons like this:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
    {
      this.state.neighbours.map( (neighbour) => {
        return (
          <Button title={neighbour.is_anchored == "0" ? 'friends' : 'add'} />
        )
      })
    }
    </View>
  );
}
```

This will show simple result reflect to neighbors' `is_anchored` value.

**Update 1:**

With your question update, there seems should be a variable `is_anchored` there. then it could be:

```js
<Button color="#00BFA5" title={is_anchored == "0" ? 'friends' : 'add'} onPress={() =>console.log("clicked")} />
```

Comment: I've tried the above but every button is with same text  `friends`.Do i need to use map method here again?

Comment: I missed to add quote to `is_anchored`, I didn't notice it's a string. try `{is_anchored == "0" ? 'friends' : 'add'}`

Comment: i'v tried this `<View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
     {
      return this.state.neighbours.map(neighbours =>
       <Button title={neighbours.no_of_friends == "0" ? 'add' : 'friends'} />
      );
     }
   </View>` but got syntax error

Comment: You're very close. remove `return` then it should works. `<View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
{
    this.state.neighbours.map(
        neighbours => <Button title={neighbours.no_of_friends == "0" ? 'add' : 'friends'} />
    )
}
</View>`

Comment: You can't use component's `state` in another component. you have to either  pass down to another component as `props`, or sync them via global variables or rxjs `Observable`.

Comment: Itz working perfectly when i removed the map method. Actually i was getting the response in a different page , i think that might be the reason.Anyway thank you much..

Comment: Sorry what do i if i want to change the color also along with text??

Comment: that could be `<Button color={neighbour. no_of_friends == "0" ? "red" : "blue"} title={neighbour. no_of_friends == "0" ? 'friends' : 'add'} />`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey please help me if there is more than one value for status `no_of_friends` ?Can i check it with or condition ?how it will be?Also how do replace the button  based on this condition

Comment: comments are full, please open a new question with detail of it